# How to shedule a method to run every month and create a credential file?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, amazon-iam

I need to rotate the IAM user key every 28 days using the Java API. I have a working API that will create a new key and delete the older one. However, the issue is at integrating this with my current application so that after 28 days it will run my method and will generate new a credential file.

The main application will be running all the time. Along with it, I will have one method that will create this credential file and this should run only after 28 days from the last updated file time.

How can I run the file creation process every 28 days? I mean how do I  calculate or trigger this method 28 days after the last creation?

I am using Quartz to schedule this method to run, but I'm getting confused calculating the number of days part and triggering it.

Here is the I am using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
        job.setName("dummyJobName");
        job.setJobClass(HelloJob.class);
        // configure the scheduler time
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\u6034690\\.aws\\credentials");
        Date lastModifiedDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        String strFormatedLastModifedDate = sdf.format(lastModifiedDate);
        System.out.println("After Format : " + strFormatedLastModifedDate);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(lastModifiedDate); // Now use today date.
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 28); // Adding 28 days
        String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        System.out.println(output);
        Date millisd = c.getTime();
        long millis = millisd.getTime();
        System.out.println(millis);

        SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger();
        trigger.setName("Test");
        trigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
        trigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
        trigger.setRepeatInterval(30000);
        // schedule it
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
```

The problem is in the part below:

```
trigger.setRepeatInterval(30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in that way..

```
GregorianCalendar executionDate = new GregorianCalendar();
executionDate .set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 28);
```

and schedule the trigger in this way..

```
Trigger repeatTrigger = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("Repeat at 28")
            .usingJobData(orderDataMap).startAt(executionDate .getTime()).forJob(job).build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(repeatTrigger );
```

You can modify Calander approach in your way there are numerous method in this api to reachout to desired timeframe.